# I get an error when I indicate the path to the Symlink 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, module, image, directory

I am using the module **[Image Optimizer](https://www.apptrian.com/image-optimizer-for-magento)** and I need to specify the media folder to optimize the pictures.

But I don’t have a media folder for the project, there is only a Symlink to the directory `/mnt/MEDIA/media/` relative to the project root. If I specify the path to the media folder in the admin panel, I get an error

project dir: `/var/www/vhosts/xxxe.de/httpdocs/`
media dir: `/mnt/MEDIA/media/`

[image]

[image]

> Scanning and reindexing failed.

```
SplFileInfo::isFile(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/xxxe.de/httpdocs/media/..) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/xxxe.de/:/tmp/:/mnt/MEDIA/media)
```

File ownership matches :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
open_basedir string
```

> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified
>   directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT
>   affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.

solution to add path to open_basedir:

```
open_basedir = "/path/to/first/folder:/path/to/second/folder"
```

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006170513-How-to-add-custom-or-additional-path-to-the-open-basedir-option-for-Plesk-domain-

- Log into Plesk
- Go to Domains > example.com > PHP Settings
- Define the custom path:`{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}{:}/example/path`